# Golang File/Directory Walker adding files multiple times

Tags: recursion, go, filesystemwatcher

So I am using the `filepath.Walk` function to monitor for changes in files recursively. `fsnotify` can't do recursive out of the box. I set up a Goroutine to monitor for changes, and then I add the paths to the watcher in the `Walk()` function.

```
func (w Watch) walkDirectories(fp string) {
    error := filepath.Walk(fp, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        // skip files
        if info == nil {
            log.Fatalf("wrong watcher package: %s", path)
        }
        if !info.IsDir() {
            return nil
        }
        if len(path) > 1 && strings.HasPrefix(filepath.Base(path), ".") {
            return filepath.SkipDir
        }
        log.Println("filepath: ", filepath)
        w.W.Add(path)
        return err
    })
    log.Println("error: ", error)
}
```

I have a custom Struct that holds a Watcher, so that I can easily add paths for it to watch. You can see it being used here: `w.W.Add(path)`. It all works great, except that files in the top level directory seem to be added twice to the watcher, or at least my hypothesis is "as many times as their are directory levels below the top level". My directory structure is such that:

```
.
├── README.md
├── languages.go
├── languages.json
├── librarymonitor.go
├── telemetryClient
└── testfiles
    ├── test.go
    ├── test.c
    ├── test.java
```

If I change a file in the testfiles directory, I get one "notification" from the watcher. If I change a file in the root, I get two. Can anyone shed light on this?
Thanks

Comment: Can't reproduce behaviour on my machine. To my mind deal is either a typo or  w.W.Add(path) which you didn't provide. Without w.W.Add(path) your code output correctly on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Check your main code, this works fine, (try [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/kT5sDgY9cV)):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "reflect"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    rootDir := ".."
    pattern := "*"
    dirs, err := GetDirectories(rootDir, pattern)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    ticker := time.NewTicker(1 * time.Second)
    for i := 1; i < 10; i++ {
        <-ticker.C
        dirs2, err := GetDirectories(rootDir, pattern)
        //fmt.Println(dirs2)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        if !reflect.DeepEqual(dirs, dirs2) {
            fmt.Println("Dir Changed: ", len(dirs), len(dirs2))
            dirs = dirs2
        }
    }
    ticker.Stop()
    fmt.Println("Done")
}

// Returns the names of the subdirectories (including their paths)
// that match the specified search pattern in the specified directory.
func GetDirectories(root, pattern string) ([]string, error) {
    dirs := make([]string, 0, 144)
    return dirs, filepath.Walk(root, func(path string, fi os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if !fi.IsDir() {
            return nil
        }
        matched, err := filepath.Match(pattern, fi.Name())
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        if !matched {
            return nil
        }
        dirs = append(dirs, path)
        return nil
    })
}
```

Sample output ( with one new dir):

```
Dir Changed:  16 17
Done
```